# Unable to get the type of an interface/class using more than one generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, typeof

Give the example code below, can anyone explain why the first `typeof()` call works successfully but the second fails?? It doesn't matter if they are classes or interfaces it fails either way.

```
interface ITestOne<T1>
{
   T1 MyMethod();
}

interface ITestMany<T1, T2>
{
   T1 MyMethod(T2 myParameter);
}

void Main()
{
    var typeOne = typeof(ITestOne<>); //This line works
    var typeTwo = typeof(ITestMany<>); //Compile error
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to let the compiler know that you're looking for the generic type with two generic arguments.  Add a comma between the angle brackets:

```
var typeTwo = typeof(ITestMany<,>);
```

Comment: DOH! Ok, there's my Homer Simpson moment of the day. Thanks so much for the quick response!! Soon as the 15min mandatory window closes, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: No worries :) We all get those moments